# How to use own version of scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, cython, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to use the hierarchical clustering implemented in `scipy/cluster/hierarchy`. However, I want to use a type of linkage function slightly different from the `weighted` linkage in this package. In particular, I figured out that I simply want to implement a weighted linkage different from the one present in the `scipy/cluster/_hierarchy_distance_update.pxi`. Instead of using a simple average like [return 0.5 * (d_xi + d_yi)](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/6db252d0105ba6fe3b23dd10d7a0da17dac0ce53/scipy/cluster/_hierarchy_distance_update.pxi#L67), I want to do a different weighted average . I wish to use weight the distance by using the `size_x` and `size_y` information to weight the distances in individual clusters.

I am not that good at figuring out:

- How to import a different version of scipy given that I have an existing version.--I know that I can fork the existing scipy from github, make the changes I desire and then download the forked version
- But then is there a way I should name the new package different from the existing scipy.
- Would there be dependency issues?

Comment: Search for the developer docs. Matt Haberland did produce some videos in this regard (at least hidden in some github issue). It's not trivial and probably would be easier on a non-windows machine. The pxi sounds like you indeed want to touch cython parts. So compilation is needed.

Comment: Well, I can also change the value returned to the `scipy/cluster/hierarchy`, simply by modifying the section where it calls the .pxi file. I will just write my preferred distance value formula with appropriate data type. That wayI stay in the python part. Well, a non elegant solution but still might work. In that case, can you make any suggestion?

Comment: Typically existing libraries are customized by defining subclasses that inherit from the library.  You use library plus your own module that does the customization.  That way there's no need to modify the library.

Comment: @hpaulj I could have attempted to do that if the enumeration for the distance was performed inside python. The function in this case is enumerated in cython and needs compilation. I am not aware of how to make such changes but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Your question is too broad. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html is a good starting point. I would probably use a virtual environment for experiments.